# Unable to build Demo Project in Android Studio 2.x

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the Navigation Drawer demo [described in the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)  that is (as of this writing) available here: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip

The zip file for this project does not contain a build.gradle file and seems to use a different structure than is conventional. My guess is that this an old project but I want to build and run it in Android Studio 2.x (currently 2.2.3). Since this is part of the official documentation I guess I might be doing something wrong, or did the creator of this file intend for me to create a gradle build file on my own?

Any help for getting this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you import an Android project you should essentially go to menu File > New > Import Project. As a result, it will automatically create a build.gradle file in case it does not exist in the project.

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete all gradle related files out side your app folder  and import project again it will rebuild and it will include all  gradle related dependencies again